Why spec command throwing unknown argument in Angular 18?
ng g c keydemo --spec=false

Error: Unknown argument.

This is coming up when I am trying to make a new component without a spec.ts file for it.
I am using Angular version 18 for this.

...because spec is not a known argument.

For Angular CLI v8 and later:
ng generate component your-component-name --skip-tests

For Angular CLI v6 and earlier
ng generate component your-component-name --spec=false


It throws an error because --spec is not a valid option. To generate a new component without a spec file, use the --skip-tests option:
ng g c keydemo --skip-tests

See the docs.
